# Having a composite key for hash map in c++

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map, boost-multi-index

I have a data structure which has,

```
<Book title>, <Author>, and <rate>
```

Since Book title or Author can be duplicated, I'd like to build a composite key.
(let's say I cannot make extra unique key, such as ID)

Since data is pretty huge, I'm using GCC unordered_map for the sake of speed,
and I built my structure like this:

```
typedef pair<string, string> keys_t
typedef unordered_map<keys_t, double> map_t;
```

Everything works okay in general,
But the problem happens when I want to refer one specific key.

For example, let's suppose I'd like to find the best-rated book among books titled as "math", or  I'd like to find the average rate of "Tolstoy"'s books. 
In this case, this becomes very bothersome, since I cannot only refer only one of the key pair.

I happened to find `boost::multi_index` but I'm having some trouble understanding the documents. 
Does anyone have some idea or guideline for this?

Solution to make multiple indices, succinct example for multi_index, any other approach, etc.. any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should also have a look at boost intrusive containers

Comment: I suggest you look at this example which demonstrates the use of composite keys: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/example/composite_keys.cpp, in addition, this page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html, describes how to define multiples indices (imagine them as "views" of the same data)

Comment: I know you said you look at the docs, but this specific example show how to form a composite key http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example7

Comment: devEvan, I think you should really put that in a proper answer, and accept that instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I'm kinda new to here, so I don't understand exactly what you mean. Do you mean that I need to answer this question by myself with that code, and accept it instead?

Comment: Yes, if that's the solution you went with then I think it would be better as an answer. Especially since it can be shown as accepted, and voted upon.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, modified. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to use `boost::multi_index`
I referred this code: [Boost multi_index composite keys using MEM_FUN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481089/boost-multi-index-composite-keys-using-mem-fun)

and here's my code for your reference.

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using namespace std;

class Book {
public:
    Book(const string &lang1, const string &lang2, const double &value) : m_lang1(lang1) , m_lang2(lang2) , m_value(value) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator << (ostream& os,const Book& n)    {
        os << n.m_lang1 << " " << n.m_lang2 << " " << n.m_value << endl;
        return os;
    }

    const string &lang1() const { return m_lang1; }
    const string &lang2() const { return m_lang2; }
    const double &value() const { return m_value; }
private:
    string m_lang1, m_lang2;
    double m_value;
};

// These will be Tag names
struct lang1 {};
struct lang2 {};
struct value {};

typedef multi_index_container <
    Book, 
    indexed_by<
        ordered_non_unique<tag<lang1>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN( Book, const string &, lang1)
        >,
        ordered_non_unique<tag<lang2>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(Book, const string &, lang2)
        >,
        ordered_non_unique<tag<value>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(Book, const double &, value), greater<double>
        >,
        ordered_unique<
            // make as a composite key with Title and Author
            composite_key<
                Book,
                BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(Book, const string &, lang1),
                BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(Book, const string &, lang2)
            >
        >
    >
> Book_set;

// Indices for iterators
typedef Book_set::index<lang1>::type Book_set_by_lang1;
typedef Book_set::index<lang2>::type Book_set_by_lang2;
typedef Book_set::index<value>::type Book_set_by_value;

int main() {

    Book_set books;
    books.insert(Book("Math", "shawn", 4.3));
    books.insert(Book("Math", "john", 4.2));
    books.insert(Book("Math2", "abel", 3.8));
    books.insert(Book("Novel1", "Tolstoy", 5.0));
    books.insert(Book("Novel1", "Tolstoy", 4.8)); // This will not be inserted(duplicated)
    books.insert(Book("Novel2", "Tolstoy", 4.2));
    books.insert(Book("Novel3", "Tolstoy", 4.4));
    books.insert(Book("Math", "abel", 2.5));
    books.insert(Book("Math2", "Tolstoy", 3.0));

    cout << "SORTED BY TITLE" << endl;
    for (Book_set_by_lang1::iterator itf = books.get<lang1>().begin(); itf != books.get<lang1>().end(); ++itf)
        cout << *itf;

    cout << endl<<"SORTED BY AUTHOR" << endl;
    for (Book_set_by_lang2::iterator itm = books.get<lang2>().begin(); itm != books.get<lang2>().end(); ++itm)
        cout << *itm;

    cout << endl<<"SORTED BY RATING" << endl;
    for (Book_set_by_value::iterator itl = books.get<value>().begin(); itl != books.get<value>().end(); ++itl)
        cout << *itl;

    // Want to see Tolstoy's books? (in descending order of rating)
    cout << endl;
    Book_set_by_lang2::iterator mitchells = books.get<lang2>().find("Tolstoy");
    while (mitchells->lang2() == "Tolstoy")
        cout << *mitchells++;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you all who made comments!

Answer (score 1):

What I did in a similar case was use a single container to contain the
objects and separate `std::multiset<ObjectType const*, CmpType>` for
each possible index; when inserting, I'd do a `push_back`, then recover
the address from `back()`, and insert it into each of the `std::set`.
(`std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_multiset` would be better in
your case: in my case, not only was the order significant, but I didn't 
have access to a recent compiler with `unordered_set` either.)

Note that this supposes that the objects are immutable once they are in
the container.  If you're going to mutate one of them, you probably should
extract it from all of the sets, do the modification, and reinsert it.

This also supposes that the main container type will never invalidate
pointers and references to an object; in my case, I knew the maximum
size up front, so I could do a `reserve()` and use `std::vector`.
Failing this, you could use `std::deque`, or simply use an `std::map`
for the primary (complete) key.

Even this requires accessing the complete element in the key.  It's not
clear from your posting whether this is enough—“books titled
math” makes me thing that you might need a substring search in the
title (and should “Tolstoy” match “Leo
Tolstoy”?).  If you want to match an arbitrary substring, either
your multiset will be very, very large (since you'll insert all possible
substrings as entries), or you'll do a linear search.  (On a long
running system where the entries aren't changing, it might be worth
compromizing: do the linear search the first time the substring is
requested, but cache the results in a multiset, so that the next time,
you can find them quickly.  It's likely that people will often use the
same substrings, e.g. “math” for any book with
“math” in its title.)

Comment: Thanks, I actually happened to build a `boost::multi_index` but your idea also helped.

Answer (score 1):

There is an article on the same subject:
http://marknelson.us/2011/09/03/hash-functions-for-c-unordered-containers/

The author, Mark Nelson, was trying to do the similar : "use of a simple class or structure to hold the person’s name", basically he's using a pair as key (just like you) for his unordered_map:

```
typedef pair<string,string> Name;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unordered_map<Name,int> ids;
    ids[Name("Mark", "Nelson")] = 40561;
    ids[Name("Andrew","Binstock")] = 40562;
    for ( auto ii = ids.begin() ; ii != ids.end() ; ii++ )
        cout << ii->first.first
        << " "
        << ii->first.second
        << " : "
        << ii->second
        << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

He realized that the unordered_map doesn’t know how to create a hash for the given key type of std::pair.
So he demonstrates 4 ways of creating a hash function for use in unordered_map.

Answer (score -1):

If it is an infrequent operation you can search for the value.

```
for(auto& p : m)
{
     if(p.second.name==name_to_find)
     {
          //you now have the element
     }
}
```

however if the map is large this will be problematic because it will be a linear procedure rather than O(log n), this is a problem because maps are inherently slow.

Comment: I somehow have the feeling that the OP already looked at it, and had some trouble understanding the very linked documentation...

Comment: not really an answer - the OP already knows of the multi_index container, so no point in linking to documentation that he's having a hard time deciphering..

Comment: @PlasmaHH, touche, I removed the boost multi index junk