# How to erase in Boost multi_index composite keys?

Tags: c++, boost, composite-key, boost-multi-index

I was checking on this 
**[Boost multi_index composite keys using MEM_FUN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481089/boost-multi-index-composite-keys-using-mem-fun)**

Can someone tell me how to implement erase function for this example ?

Now I am doing

```
Name_set_by_last::iterator mitchells = names.get<last>().find("mitchell");
names.erase(mitchells );//shows error
```

Answer (score 6):

`names.get<last>().erase(mitchells);`